Flutter - macOS and iOS share code, different builds
I have my iOS app at a good MVP state now and would like to start building the MacOS app out. However, I do not understand how to structure the new project and still share core source files?
For instance, I have a main.dart in lib that starts the iOS (Android) app.
But this would be incompatible with macOS because the UIs would differ.
Any pointers how to structure the project now?

In a perfect world, your UI would be flexible between platforms such that you would not need different entry-points in your application.
However, we all know that is easier said then done. To answer your question, you can provide multiple main.dart files. Granted you give them different names. Such as main_macos.dart.
Once you have this new main file, you have to specify it when you build flutter. To do so, you would use the command flutter build -t main_macos.dart ..extra build args.. and this will build your Flutter project with that other main file.
Hopefully that helps and if you need other information, please leave a comment and I can assist further.

Thanks, I'll try that when I get back to the project. Have a great day!

Or would it be better to just use the main.dart and , depending on which platform is currently active switch to a different view? I am afraid that some plugins are not available for desktop that I use in the mobile version...

You could do that as well. That is a valid approach and widely used. As with everything, it depends on your use case.

Just did and it works. My concern however here is that all mobile dependencies will be linked into the MacOS / Win binary even not used. I am not sure how flutter builds the bundle, but I assume that might happen...?
